# How can I get all roles of a user by user id in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is it possible in Spring Security to get all roles of a user if I only know a username? I am thinking of something like this:

```
List<String> userRoles=veryCleverObject.getRolesByUsername("user123");
```

I know how to do this for current user but not for any user. My workaround is I query it with JpaRepository from the db but this is not a good solution for obvious reasons.

I need this in a simple user management modul in my app where I list the users and I would like to show their roles.

How can I do that in Spring Security?

Comment: Why isn't querying the database to get user roles a good solution? I suppose that when the user logs in, you find his roles in your DB, so why not just list the user's roles on that page from the same DB?

Comment: Because if somewhere I should use for instance Ldap authentication instead of JDBC then I should rewrite/extend my role quering logic. It would better solution if Spring Security do that job with an interface to query the roles of a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: no, as authentication may be made via `AuthenticationProvider` or even `AuthenticationManager` which, as a rule, require some credentials along with the username; even more, they require this data to be packed in some `Authentication` class instance. Usually, you don't have any credentials, only a username, and you don't know how to build that `Authentication` in a generic way.

But if you only use `UserDetailsService`-based mechanisms (like JDBC authentication http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ or LDAP authentication https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ you could just use that `UserDetailsService` instance which has the following method:

```
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
```

It finds `UserDetails` by username, from which you can get user roles (aka granted authorities).

`UserDetailsService` may be obtained via dependency injection.